# Queryable.Where Method works only on List<> but not DbSet<>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I simply wanted to filter results I query from database similar to:

```
var resultsWithNullSomeColumn = db.Table.Where(x => x.someColumn == null)
```

This does not work!

However if I get the whole table from db and convert it to a `List<>` then I can filter the rows with null `someColumn`

```
var wholeTable = db.Table.ToList();
var resultsWithNullSomeColumn = wholeTable.Where(x => x.someColumn == null);
```

My question is: Why `Where` works only on `List<>` but not `DbSet<>`

Comment: What is the type of `someColumn`?

Comment: `someColumn`is `Nullable<int>`

Answer (score 0):

```
db.Table.Where(x => x.someColumn == null).ToList();
```

Should work. You need to call `ToList()` to build your query results. Using your example:

```
var resultsWithNullSomeColumn = db.Table.Where(x => x.someColumn == null);

var listResults = resultsWithNullSomeColumn.ToList();
```

Should also work.

Comment: I already tried the first, it does not work. But the second does. I suspect the issue has to do with `null` because I tried an `int` and both worked. Thank you for your answer